# Can VBA change visibility of a sheet while integrity of workbook structure is locked?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to lock the integrity of a workbook so that users can't delete or move sheets. However I would still like to be able to hide and unhide sheets using VBA. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You may unprotect the workbook, do your stuff and protect the workbook back:

```
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="your_password"
'[... do your stuff...]
ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="your_password", Structure:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when you set the protection.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="myPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

The effect is that the user can't change anything that you haven't allowed (there might be more to the above code than I show here) while the *UserInterfaceOnly* property allows your code to act as if no protection existed.